# Can WCF bound to Amazon SQS?

Tags: wcf, amazon-sqs

We have WCF service with netMSMQBinding which works seamlessly. Now we are going to host application and hence WCF on Amazon AWS server. Since AWS provides its own implementation for Queuing message - SQS(Simple Queue Service), idea has come forward to bind WCF to SQS rather than MSMQ.

has anybody tried this before? Any help is much appreciated.